# Android: Multiple gridView rows responding to item click

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-listview, android-gridview

Im trying to change (onClick) the background of an ImageView inside my GridView, but whem i click it, the selected row and another random one react to the click. Below is my code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final int index = position;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_galeria_modelo, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.favoriteStar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_fav_star);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.favoriteStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!holder.isFavorited) {
                holder.isFavorited = true;
                holder.favoriteStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
            } else { 
                holder.isFavorited = false;
                holder.favoriteStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_grey);
            }
        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set a unique id for the ImageView(s) in java or xml which *might* be something like:

Java (multiple views being created with repeat of same code:

```
ViewHolder vh;
ImageView iv;
View vi;
int location = 0;

vi = view;
vh = new ViewHolder();

// Use to get the current ImageView being worked on.
vh.iv = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

// Use to set new id for the ImageView currently being worked on.
vh.iv.setId(location++);
```

xml (multiple views in xml layout):

```
<!-- Copy and paste and new name for each and every view needed --> 
android:id="@+id/id_name_here"
```

Now because *every* id is now unique the listener can pick the correct view.

EXAMPLE:

```
public void clickListener(View view) {
final int id = view.getId();

// Can now get the unique id of the exact ImageView that was clicked
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(id);

// Will now set new image for and only for the correct ImageView that was clicked.
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
}
```

There might be other code changes or additions needed as well perhaps such as the way that the views are created. But a unique id does keep each view separate allowing you to set or get of only the correct view and no other.